# String Buffer method "toString"

Tags: java

what happens when you call "toString" method without a string variable to collect value that is returned? 
For eg: here are two code snippets I tired. the first one gives the correct answer, the second gives a wrong answer but it still compiles. If "toString" method is meant to return a value, shouldn't I get a compiler error for the second block of code?

```
StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer(s); //s is a string input taken from user
        sb.reverse();
        String rev=sb.toString();
        if(s.equals(rev)){
            System.out.println("yes");
/*second try*/
StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer(s); 
        sb.reverse();
        sb.toString();//what is happening here?
        if(s.equals(sb)){
            System.out.println("yes");
```

Comment: nothing. Java doesn't care if you capture the return value. It just runs the method and then does nothing with the result

Comment: a `StringBuffer` will never be equal to a `String`. You should read the Docs and learn how `equals` is specified

Comment: `if(s.equals(sb)){` You cannot compare a `String` and a `StringBuffer`. I mean you can but it's like comparing apples and oranges. As others have pointed out, Java doesn't care if you capture the return value. I hope you understand now

Comment: Please don't use StringBuffer as StringBuilder replaced it more than ten years ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> sb.toString();//what is happening here?

You are converting the `StringBuilder` object to `String` which is good but you are not storing the return value to a `String` type and using it later in your `equals` call. You should do it the following way:

```
String reversedString = sb.toString();
if(s.equals(reversedString )){
```

Or simply

```
if(s.equals(sb.toString())){
```

Right now you are comparing `s` with `sb` using the `equals` method of `String` class. This method returns `false` if the object passed in as an argument is not an instance of `String` class. Since `StringBuilder` object `sb` is not an instance of `String`, the `equals` method returns false.

Answer (score 1):

It is simple to understand.

**In the first case**, the value is returned and is being referenced by a variable so that you can make use of that value later on.

**In the second case**, the value is returned just like before but it is not being referenced by any variable. Thus, the value simply goes into waste and can not be used or manipulated later on.

Answer (score 0):

toString will return whatever the toString method of the object returns.
Try System.out.println(sb.toString); to see what it is returning.

Comment: Isn't that what you want, @Nan?

Answer (score 0):

`StringBuffer#toString()` returns a string, if you don't place that returned value in a variable then nothings happens and the information you've requested is gone.

Answer (score 0):

`.toString()` is a method that returns a string, it does not convert that StringBuffer into a string.

`if(s.equals(sb.toString()))` would work because it is comparing `s` to the value of `sb` as a string, even though it is not assigning the value to variable.

Answer (score 0):

In Java you don't have to check or store any return value.
`sb.toString()` is executed and the return value is truncated.

Please note that the method must be executed, because there might be side effects. To test it out, you might implement in your class:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    System.out.println("toStringTest");
    return super.toString();
}
```

"toStringTest" will be put out!